# Why does this Java code not convert files?

Tags: java, oop, uppercase, lowercase, converters

Write a Java program that reads a text file and writes the content into a new file. During the read-write process, convert all the upper case letters into lower case ones. In other words, your programming task is to create a new file with the same content of the original file, only that all the upper case letters are converted into lower case ones in the new file

When I run this code, no matter the file name it is showing it does not exist. I have created a file named `input.txt` and it is supposed to convert the data into all lowercase letters.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UpperCaseFileConverter
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userFileName;

    System.out.println( "Please enter file name. Please enter \"input.txt\" ");
    userFileName = scanner.nextLine();

    File file = new File(userFileName);

    while(!file.exists() )
    {
        System.out.println( userFileName + " does not exist. Please try again.Please enter \"input.txt\" ");
        userFileName = scanner.nextLine();
        file = new File(userFileName);
    }

    Scanner fileToScan = new Scanner(file);
    PrintWriter fileToWrite = new PrintWriter ("OUTPUT.TXT");

    while(fileToScan.hasNext() )
    {
        fileToWrite.println( fileToScan.nextLine().toLowerCase() );
    }

    fileToWrite.close();
    fileToScan.close();
    }
}
```

The output should create a new file but it just keeps saying the files do not exist.

Comment: Well, where is the file located? Debug your code, check what path `file` actually is by getting its absolute path and comparing it to where the file actually is.

Comment: Note that there is a mismatch between `hasNext` and `nextLine`. `hasNext` pairs with `next`, `hasNextLine` pairs with `nextLine`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code that means it wouldn't read that file - it works for me as expected. You're probably putting the file in the wrong place. (Do `System.out.println(new File("").getAbsolutePath());` to find the directory it expects.)

Comment: Stop editing the question. You asked the question, accept an answer if that solved your problem but don't change the question significantly or a mod will get involved.

Answer (score 1):

When you are running your code in an IDE, the code won't actually run *inside* the folder that your Java files are saved. Instead it might run with the current directory set to the root folder of the whole project.

You can get the value of the current working directory by running and printing the return value of `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()`. That will tell you where to put input.txt and also where `output.txt` will be saved.